# ie 8, 9 body background position

Tags: html, css, background, position, internet-explorer-9

I can not fix on problem.

IE 8 and 9 center bady background vertical, when it have to be 0 at top.

some ideas?
thx a lot

That was my fault. The problem was caused by son js script, that I was using at the beginning of development. Sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either of these properties for the body element will work:

```
background-position: 50% 0;
```

or

```
background-position: center top;
```

You were already using "center top" for the background property of your body element, yet you also overwrote that with the inline style:

```
<body style="background-position: 50% 50%">
```

Remove the inline style. It should work.

Comment: hmmm, where did you find the <body style="background-position: 50% 50%">?

Comment: Now i've got it, that was a js script